# Jmeter + selenium api - Java script undled error

Tags: javascript, selenium, jmeter

While working on Jmeter with selenium webdriver, I have noticed unhandled error "016/02/17 16:51:47 ERROR - com.googlecode.jmeter.plugins.webdriver.sampler.WebDriverSampler: :14:94 Expected , but found ;
WDS.browser.findElement(pkg.By.cssSelector('.tile.default.sidebar-tile-buynow.active').click();
                                                                                              ^ in  at line number 14 at column number 94 
2016/02/17 16:51:49 ERROR - com.googlecode.jmeter.plugins.webdriver.sampler.WebDriverSampler: :4:69 Expected , but found ;
WDS.browser.findElement(pkg.By.cssSelector('.menu-ico.admin').click(); 
                                                                     ^ in  at line number 4 at column number 69"

Answer (score 1):

There is something wrong with your JavaScript code, I expect something like unbalanced quotes or braces, not closed parenthesis, etc.

Double check your code using [JavaScript IDE](http://www.ilovefreesoftware.com/14/featured/4-free-ide-for-javascript.html) with syntax highlighting - it should help. Or update your question with full code so community could take a look and help to figure out the problem.

Just in case check out [The WebDriver Sampler: Your Top 10 Questions Answered](https://blazemeter.com/blog/webdriver-sampler-your-top-10-questions-answered) article.